# Возможно ли обойтись без jQuery для написания качественых сайтов на чистом Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возможно ли обойтись без *jQuery* для написания качественных сайтов на чистом Javascript?

Посоветуйте, как это сделать.

Comment: Можно, да. jQuery устроен с чистым JavaScript'ом, значит, всё, что возможно с jQuery, возможно и без.

Comment: Есть куча других фреймвороков, на одном jquery мир клином не сошелся. Почему же без него этот мир представить не могут?

Comment: я посмотрел исходники многих сайтов и где-то 90% сайтов на jQuery

Comment: Так вот, значит другие 10% успели без jQuery написать сайт.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

У jQuery есть 2 основные задачи:

1. Сделать код максимально кроссбраузерным (привет IE6).
2. Предоставить набор методов, упрощающих рутинные задачи (работа с DOM, AJAX запросы, анимация).

Все современные бразузеры следуют стандартам (более-менее) и проблема кроссбраузерного кода уже не стоит так остро как раньше. Поэтому, если ваша задача - писать код только под современные браузеры, пункт 1 (почти наверняка) можно вычеркивать.

Что касается рутинных операций, то тот за последнее время тоже наметился существенный прогресс. Одни только методы `document.querySelector` и `document.querySelectorAll` позволяют полностью (или почти полностью) отказаться от использования конструкций вида `$('...')` для выборки элементов дерева DOM.

Безусловно, еще есть ряд операций, применение jQuery в которых позволяет существенно сократить количество шаблонного кода (например, AJAX запросы), но сказать, что эти задачи нельзя решить без jQuery было бы не верно.

При разработке каждого отдельного сайта нужно в первую очередь исходить из требований к нему. Если на сайте нужна галерея, то глупо пытаться писать что-то свое. Проще использовать готовое решение, которое, в 99% случаев, зависит от jQuery. В таких проектах без jQuery не обойтись.

Отдельно стоит отметить, что jQuery не единственная в своем роде. Для тех же задач есть, например, Zepto, имеющий свои преимущества и недостатки.

В сети есть множество статей, рассматривающих целесообразность тащить jQuery в проект. Вот одна из таких статей: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com (другие легко ищутся в Google).

**Резюмирую**: да, можно сделать сайт без jQuery. Все зависит от требований к сайту и необходимости поддержки старых браузеров.

Comment: Те кто минусуют, вы хотя бы комментируйте за что.